# bottom border disappears in chrome in submenu

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

On a submenu on a website (lainegabriel.net), I have bottom borders that disappear on some of the links in the submenu under "Buy".  This only appears in Chrome; Firefox and Safari render it properly.  I believe the anchor tag is somehow overlapping over elements in the unordered list.  But I simply cannot figure out what is happening.

And the problem goes away if you navigate to a page inside the submenu.  Otherwise, some of the borders disappear.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul.sub-menu li{
               float:none}
```

replace this with `ul.sub-menu li{
                                  display:block;
                                   width:100%;}`